# moving images in java applet

Tags: java, image, animation, applet

The question is about java applet programming
I used a java applet to draw an image in the paint method using the following code:

```
       g.draw(Myimage,0,0,this);
```

The image was drawn on the screen, But what i want to do is to be able to change the position of this image without clearing the screen and without drawing blank image in the previous position of the image..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"The image was drawn on the screen, But what i want to do is to be able to change the position of this image without clearing the screen and without drawing blank image in the previous position of the image.. "*  Try voodoo.  If that does not achieve the stated effect (without smearing) for this use case, I doubt anything else will.

Comment: I don't know what is "voodo" .. but I will look about
thankssss

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw another image in other place. Just change the parameters in your code. For more details about graphics object follow the link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Other wise why dont you simply extend GraphicsProgram class provided by acm. It has a move function which will exactly do what you want to do. Check out the link.

http://jtf.acm.org/rationale/graphics-package.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, you want to create an animation where the image moves from one spot to other in Java?

Comment: I can't extend another class since I extend java applet :)

Comment: You can always write a separate public class within your package that extends  GraphicsProgram. Then write a public function that uses move() function from GraphicsProgram.  Then use the function in the class that extends Applet.

Answer (score 1):

> But what i want to do is to be able to change the position of this image without clearing the screen and without drawing blank image in the previous position of the image..

Then use a `JLabel`. When you want to move the label you use the `setLocation()` method. The `RepaintManager` will repaint the location where the label was and then paint the label in its new location so you don't have to worry about calculating the area affected by the move.